# Extract rows which haven't been extracted already using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

I have a table `Customers`. I'm trying to design a way which will extract data from `Customers` table daily and create a CSV of this data. I want to pick only those records which haven't been extracted yet. How can I keep track of whether it has been extracted or not? I cannot alter the `Customers` table to add a flag.

So far I'm planning to use a Stage table which will have this flag. So I'm writing a stored procedure to get the data from the `Customers` table and have the flag set to 0 for each of these records. And use SSIS to create the CSV after pulling this data from stage table and once the records have been extracted into CSV update the staging table with flag=1 for those records.

What is a good design for this problem?

**Customer** table:

```
CustomerID | Name | RecordCreated | RecordUpdated
```

Comment: I don't  derstand what is your question is? because you already say a good design for this `Extracted Bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

Answer (score 0):

Create another table `tblExportedEmpID` with a column `CustomerID`. Add the customer id of each customer extracted from the `Customer` table into that new table. And to extract the customer from the `Customer` table which are not extracted yet, you can use this query :

```
select * from customer where customerid not in(select customerid from tblExportedEmpID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `RecordCreated` and `RecordUpdated`.  Why even bother with a separate record-per table if you have that information?

You'll need to create a table or equivalent "saved until next run" data area.    The first thing you have your script do is grab the current time, and whatever was stored in that data area.  Then, have your statement query everything:

```
SELECT <list of columns and transformation>
FROM Customers
WHERE recordCreated >= :lastRunTime AND recordCreated < :currentRunTime
```

(or `recordUpdated`, if you need to re-extract if the customer's name changes)
Note that you want the [exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (`<`) to cover the case where your stored timestamp has less resolution than the mechanism getting the timestamp.

For the last step, store off your run start - whatever the script grabbed for "current time" - into the "saved until next run" data area.